# Is it possible to have a number with a different base for each digit?

Tags: notation

My main thinking on this is time, where we have days, hours, minutes, and seconds, all of which use a different base (we represent them in base 10 but you get the point). Is it mathematically acceptable/possible to write a time down as one number in the form $a_{100}b_{365.24}c_{24}d_{60}e_{60}$ ?

And what would you call this "composite base"? I have 3 different ways of thinking about it. 1) Just name it something, so because this is measuring time it would be base $t$ My thinking was with a number with $n$ digits, the base would be the $n$th root of the product of all the bases, that way any number with a normal base would still fit this rule, but this wouldn't be a unique number because any 4 digit composite base number that multiplies to $31,536,000$ would have the same base as the composite base shown above, which would be $2\sqrt[4]{1971000}$. 3) You would somehow hash the set of bases into a unique number. That's my take on this, but I hope that I'm not the first to come across this and an actual mathematician has figured something better out.

### Examples

To represent numbers larger than 9, I will use A-Z for $10-35$, then a-z for $36-61$, and I'm too lazy to think of symbols for anything larger than that so we'll just ignore that for now and not include higher numbers for the examples.

1. 12 days, 3 hours, 42 minutes, and 10 seconds => $C3gA = 1,050,130_{10}$ seconds
2. 56 days, 9 hours, 19 minutes, and 0 seconds => $u9J0 = 4,871,940_{10}$ seconds

Comment: Can you please show how did you derived the numbers in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible, and it seems like you've already found a good example. More precisely, I would say that numbers don't have bases, they just have representations in bases. Just as with regular bases, these mixed bases clearly have unique representations for integers, and I think fractions and "decimal" representations of irrational numbers probably work fine too. Indeed, given the probable ease with which one could generalize the notion of basis, there might not be too much interesting to say from a pure math perspective.

As to what to call such mixed bases, Googling around, I came up with "mixed radix", which yields a nice Wikipedia article.

Comment: O thanks! I think "mixed radix" is basically what I was looking for. And you are completely correct that numbers only have representations, because the values won't change, you could count to 100 with 100 sticks or with base 64 numbers and the value 100 wouldn't change

Answer (score 0):

You can consider our usual degrees/minutes/seconds for angular measurement or miles/feet/inches to be examples of what you are saying.  For angular measure you can view the degrees measurement as being in base $360$.  We just use three characters to represent one digit.  Similarly the minutes and seconds are in base $60$ and we use two characters to represent one digit.  We just chose not to use letters to get each base $60$ digit into one character.   Alternately you can view the minutes and seconds as having one base $6$ digit and one base $10$ digit each.  The problem with this approach is why one would want to use it, not whether it can be done.  We do it with angles, time, and imperial units all the time because we are used to it.

You shouldn't confuse numbers, which have a value independent of the way we express them, and numerals, which are expressions in a particular base.  These mixed bases are inconvenient for computation.  Even the carries in addition and multiplication are hard (thank you, metric system), let alone roots.  I can certainly ask what is the fifth root of $123_{360}45_{60}23_{60}$.  The easiest way I can think of to do that is to convert to base $10$, take the root, and convert back.  We have
$$123_{360}45_{60}23_{60}=123\cdot 3600+45\cdot 60 + 23=445523_{10}\\
\sqrt[5]{445523}\approx 13.48_{10}$$
and we are within the first digit that should be written in base $60$.  We need to define what we are doing with numbers less than $1$.